# Firebase ValueListener not work the second or third time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Profile page, I set a listener to keep my MainActivity.currUser alwyas has the the updated value, and each editTextView i put code to save the values to my DB.
The problem is i get an error when i move to the other editTextView.

here is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_page);

    // [START initialize_database_ref]
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // [END initialize_database_ref]

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress); 
....... another findViewById


    listenProfileOnce();

    loadUserClass();


    editTextName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus) {
                if (!editTextName.getText().equals(MainActivity.currUser.getName())) {  //process only if changes occurs
                    //reflect the changes and update the db + current user object
                    MainActivity.currUser.setName(editTextName.getText().toString());
                    mDatabase.child("Users").child(MainActivity.currUser.getUID()).child("name").setValue(MainActivity.currUser.getName());
                }

            }

        }
    });

    editTextAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus) {
                if (!editTextAddress.getText().equals(MainActivity.currUser.getAddress())) {  //process only if changes occurs
                    //reflect the changes and update the db + current user object
                    MainActivity.currUser.setAddress(editTextAlamat.getText().toString());
                    mDatabase.child("Users").child(MainActivity.currUser.getUID()).child("address").setValue(MainActivity.currUser.getAddress());
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

My Listener :

```
private void listenProfile() {

    mDatabase.child(MainActivity.currUser.getUID()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            MainActivity.currUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            // ...
        }
           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
               // Getting User Class data failed...
               Log.w(TAG, "loadUserData:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
               // ...

        }
    });
```

My LoadUserData :

```
    public void loadUserClass() {


    editTextName.setText(MainActivity.currUser.getName());
    editTextAddress.setText(MainActivity.currUser.getAddress());

}
```

When it first run, all good, all data successfully loaded in my EditTextViews

The error always raised when i want to edit the editTextViews, where the onFocusChange executed, while in the equal checking method.

```
if (!editTextAddress.getText().equals(MainActivity.currUser.getAddress()))
```

because `MainActivity.currUser.getAddress()` suddenly returns NULL.
this is happening in `getName`.  I don't know why my `MainActivity.currUser` lost its value.

Comment: Could you add the error log?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.phielosoft.hnbssalonspa.User.getAddress()' on a null object reference at com.phielosoft.hnbssalonspa.ProfileActivity$4.onFocusChange(ProfileActivity.java:136)

Comment: if(MainActivity.currUser.getAddress() != null){ if(!editTextAddress.getText().toString().equals(MainActivity.currUser.getAddress()))) }..try this

Comment: i actually want to know why my user object return null, not how to prevent the error arise